# python datetime strptime error ValueError: time data does not match format for linux ls output format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am not sure why I am getting an error from python for this date format. I am passing a linux "ls -sl" command output formatted timestamp to python's datetime's strptime function but it is saying the format does not match.

Code:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = 'Jul 22 16:36 2020'
date_format_str = '%b %d %M:%H %Y'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, date_format_str)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Jul 22 16:36 2020' does not match format '%b %d %M:%H %Y'
```

I am following python's [datetime documentation for the format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), i thought this looked right, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Your pattern is wrong, ``'%b %d %H:%M %Y'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
date_format_str = '%b %d %H:%M %Y'
```

does not exist 36 hours

Answer (score 1):

Your minute and hour are swapped!

Try this for your formatting: `'%b %d %H:%M %Y'`